# not a particularly

Tags: articles

*I am not particularly an ardent jazz fan.*

*I am not a particularly ardent jazz fan.*

I am not sure about the position of the article in the above sentence. Can you tell me which sentence is correct?

Comment: It depends on whether **particularly** is meant to modify **ardent** (degree) or the predicate **am not** (as a sort of qualifier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second is correct in what I think you are trying to say.

> I am not a particularly ardent jazz fan.

The first one could also be used, but as noted in the comments, it would modify the word "not" as opposed to "ardent". (This is an unclear way to express it; emphasis on the "particularly" would be required.)

As a side note, "ardent" is not a word that many native speakers use or would even understand. A better word would be "enthusiastic".

Comment: Good answer, except that I disagree about native speakers not understanding "ardent".  It's not a particularly rare or difficult word, and it's actually about half as common as "enthusiastic" in Ngrams: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ardent%2Centhusiastic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cardent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Centhusiastic%3B%2Cc0